# Error while installing ROS Indigo in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, ros

I get an error while installing the 4th step of ROS Indigo in Ubuntu 14.04.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

Error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro-modules_0.7.0-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro_0.7.0-100_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone help me regarding this? I am a new Ubuntu 14.04 user.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the complete apt output. The summary is not enough to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same errors with yours when I re-installed the ROS-Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.
I solved this problem following the 3 steps:

1. Remove ROS-Indigo: `sudo apt-get purge ros-*`
2. Update: `sudo apt-get update`
3. Upgrade: `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Maybe it will take a while.